# Update y Select en la misma sentencia

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una sentencia sql donde quiero unir update con select pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1093. Table 'a' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data 0.000 sec
```

Mi sentencia es la siguiente:

```
update inv_articulo set ref = (select concat(c.prefijo_cat, '-', lpad(a.pk_articulo, 4, '0')) from inv_categoria as c 
inner join inv_tipoarticulo as t on c.pk_categoria = t.fk_categoria
inner join inv_articulo as a on t.pk_tipo = a.tipo_articulo 
where a.tipo_articulo = 26 and a.pk_articulo = 16)
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: puedes ejecutar el select aparte, y ver si es correcta la consulta? parece que es cosa de las uniones, pero tal como tienes tabulado el texto no se ve.

Comment: @Jakala Sí, la consulta la ejecuto aparte y el resultado es el que deseo

Comment: Prueba así: `update inv_articulo t1,
(select concat(c.prefijo_cat, '-', lpad(a.pk_articulo, 4, '0')) ref from inv_categoria c 
inner join inv_tipoarticulo t on c.pk_categoria = t.fk_categoria
inner join inv_articulo a on t.pk_tipo = a.tipo_articulo 
where a.tipo_articulo = 26 and a.pk_articulo = 16) t2 
set t1.ref = t2.ref` y comenta el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `mysql` primero coloca todo el `join` y después la sentencia del `SET`.  Deberá quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
update from inv_categoria as c 
inner join inv_tipoarticulo as t on c.pk_categoria = t.fk_categoria
inner join inv_articulo as a on t.pk_tipo = a.tipo_articulo 
set ref = (select concat(c.prefijo_cat, '-', lpad(a.pk_articulo, 4, '0')) 
where a.tipo_articulo = 26 and a.pk_articulo = 16)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciona perfectamente!